# Clipped oauth response in user-agent flow?

Tags: oauth2

I'm developing an app that authenticates to salesforce using the oauth2 user-agent flow. It works fine most of the time, but in the last fe days, sometimes I get clipped data in the url fragment. It is missing the access_token and only has a part of the instance_url. Here is an example.

```
//na13.salesforce.com&id=https://login.salesforce.com/id/00D30000000xxxxxxx/0053000000xxxxxxxx&issued_at=1395866445710&signature=FLnnvl332b5D9RzFNqOcMmjNTZljWB7zAI8l0bNZtoA=&scope=api+web
```

Has anybody else seen this? Any idea on how to fix it? I have tried switching browsers, clearing the cache, clearing the cookies, but no luck.